# lubridate - extract a two digit day from a date

Tags: r, tidyr, lubridate

I need to extract days as two digit days from dates.

For example:

```
date <- as.Date(01-01-2016)
```

- `year(date)` would give '2016'
- `month(date)` would yield '1'
- `day(date)` would return '1'

I want `month()` and `day()` to return '01'

The standard %D or %M, don't seem to work here. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that your 'date' is in a Date Format the format.Date() function should do the trick:

```
format.Date(date, "%m")
```

Note: In your question:

```
date <- as.Date(01-01-2016)
```

will not return 'date' in a Date Format. It will return an error because the argument you supplied to as.Date is taken as a numeric. You might want to supply your date as a character string and specify the format it is written in, something like:

```
date <- as.Date("01-01-2016", format = "%m-%d-%Y") 
format.Date(date, "%m")
```

If you do not specify the format, as.Date will try the format "%Y-%m-%d".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr(yourdate, starPosition, endPosition)`:

```
DATE <- 2020-09-01
        12345678**9***10*

DAY2DIGITS <- substr(DATE, **9**, *10*)

DAY2DIGITS = 01
```